# ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence when fetching records in batches

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am using Hibernate 5.4.24.Final with Oracle database (19c) and when trying to fetch records in batches, i get the following error after retrieving 60k records. Could someone please advice how to resolve it?

Error:

18:54:10,224 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-4) SQL Error: 1002, SQLState: 24000

18:54:10,224 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-4) ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence

Query:

```
List<Object[]> objectInMemList = new ArrayList<>();
final BigDecimal count = (BigDecimal) entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT (RP.id) AS count FROM TABLE1 RP INNER JOIN TABLE2 CS ON RP.ID = ?1 AND RP.CUSTOMER_ID = CS.ID ORDER BY RP.CREATION_DATE").setParameter(1, 123456).getSingleResult();

int numberOfRequests = count.intValue() < 20000 ? 1 : (int)Math.ceil(count.intValue() / 20000);

for(int req = 0; req < numberOfRequests; req++) {
    final Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT RP.ID AS id, RP.field1, CS.field2 AS field2, CS.field3 AS field3, RP.field2 AS rpfield2 FROM TABLE1 RP INNER JOIN TABLE2 CS ON RP.Id = ?1 AND RP.CUSTOMER_ID = CS.ID")
.setFirstResult(req*20000).setMaxResults(20000).setHint(QueryHints.READ_ONLY, true).setParameter(1, 123456);
    final List<Object[]> resultList = query.getResultList();
    objectInMemList.addAll(resultList);
}
```

Reason for batch query: To retrieve millions of records and to avoid timeout

I checked about this error online but it was all related to INSERT/UPDATE or SQL procedures. As i am making a select query, i am bit confused where does this error occurs from as the entire requests occurs in one single thread ?

Comment: Probably - just a guess - you are trying to fetch a record after the last result of the query. I suggest to log the intermediate results of your computation to check it. Especially the count, numberOfRequests and req*20000

Comment: I am trying to retrieve a half a million records (count = 499876, numberOfRequests = 25 and setFirstResult is a multiple of 20000). It started to retrieve till 60k after that, it starts to fail with the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. For some reason, i get this error when a transaction is timed out. Increasing the transaction time out resolved this issue